# How to delete a word, which was typed mistakenly, from Safari autocomplete recommendations?

Tags: keyboard, safari, catalina, dictionary

I just typed a word mistakenly, and this typo is being listed for the autocomplete words. How can I remove this word from Safari recommendations, in order words, how can I command Safari to unlearn it?

Things I've tried so far:

- Delete the cookies of the website that this word was typed
- The word is not listed in the `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`

p.s. My OS is `10.15.3`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the solution myself. Hope it helps others MacOS users:

Go to `Safari Settings`, the select the `AutoFill` tab. Click the `Edit` button of the `Other forms` option. Locate the related website, and click the `Remove` button.